# Why does my main context go over the header?

Tags: html

When I put in my header (i have already put in my context) it just puts the header underneath what the context is so you can't see the header.

I have already tried changing the padding and the other sizes but none work

https://jsfiddle.net/L30trdfn/1/`This is the full code of my website`

What should happen is that the description and avatar ECT should go under the navbar and fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS code Like this

```
.split {
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.black{background-color: #f5f5f5;}
.red{background-color: #f00;}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Corresponding html like this

```
<div class="split">
<div class="col black">
  <div class="centered">
    <img src="avatar1.png" alt="Avatar woman">
    <h2>Fortnitewinner21</h2>
    <p>Co-Owner of FSX/XP11 and is the Head Website devolper</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col red">
  <div class="centered">
    <img src="avatar2.png" alt="Avatar man">
    <h2>MasterPilot</h2>
    <p>Owner of FSX/XP11, He plays a big part in making the server run smoothley</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Change the `img src` according to your sources

```css
{
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #9099A2;
}

/* Header/Blog Title */
.header {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: #6D7993;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

/* Navbar container */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: indianred;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
    
    
/* Left column */
.leftcolumn {   
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}

/* Right column */
.rightcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #9099A2;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

/* Fake image */
.fakeimg {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Add a card effect for articles */
.card {
  background-color: #D5D5D5;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}



.split {
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.black{background-color: #f5f5f5;}
.red{background-color: #f00;}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
}

.centered img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Welcome To FSX/XP11</h1>
  <p>The Home of Flight Sim</p>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">Gallery</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Flight Planner
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="flight.html">Flight Strips</a>
      <a href="no.html">Login</a>
      <a href="Register.html">Register</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="split">
<div class="col black">
  <div class="centered">
    <img src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=2&ik=61315df9c6&attid=0.1&permmsgid=msg-f:1648390313577802256&th=16e04241b3ffea10&view=fimg&sz=s0-l75-ft&attbid=ANGjdJ8KWZCU9VW1k7NdYrm1ZoOE30R5M9Aoeokzr0KSjzE53wP1UvEZhJkACRl5RpKmGQs8W9TlWHfQME7CgcCB3TKlJ8lpdJYRU7dwfDfGHHHJvD455hCYQa4OAos&disp=emb&realattid=ii_k26gkdq90" alt="Avatar woman">
    <h2>Fortnitewinner21</h2>
    <p>Co-Owner of FSX/XP11 and is the Head Website devolper</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col red">
  <div class="centered">
    <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar man">
    <h2>MasterPilot</h2>
    <p>Owner of FSX/XP11, He plays a big part in making the server run smoothley</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It WORKS!! i just had to do a bit of tinkering to the  sizes and it all looked good! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS : \

you had given fixed position in `.split` and also used absolute position in  `.centered`. I hope you got your answer

```
.split {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: i tried putting it in but it did not work. in some ways it did because it put it under but it squezed it together? and didnt keey its origanal state?

Comment: I have user flex in the case : https://jsfiddle.net/w78hs4nc/1/